# Сортировка ключей в HashMap

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Как отсортировать объект типа HashMap по ключу ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте реализацию [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), в данном случае Java сама будет отсортировывать данные по ключу.

```
Map<String, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>(yourHashMap);
```

**UPD** Сортировка будет проходить согласно методу compareTo класса, которым является ключ

Comment: Мне надо отсортировать результат по возрастанию кода ASCII, она же так и отсортирует, если массив у меня  Character ?

Comment: @faoxis, то есть в качестве ключа используется класс Character?

Comment: Да, вот: HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

Comment: Можно взять keySet() для Вашего Map'а. И отсортировать его. Если прям надо получить отсортированный вывод по ключу. И далее вывод по отсортированному Set'у в цикле.

Comment: А можно пример ?

Comment: А как сделать сортировку в обратном порядке ?

Comment: @faoxis, как вариант изменить логику метода compareTo объекта